# Liquibase Slowness When Creating Indexes

Tags: java, oracle, liquibase

I recently upgraded my Java Liquibase version from 3.5.3 to 3.6.3

I have a very heavy environment where there are lots of databases and tables (I am using Oracle).
On this environment, I am trying to execute a huge changelog file where I create tables and indices.

Find below a small part of the changelog.

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.2.xsd">
    
    ...
    ...
    ...

   <changeSet author="me" id="tableCreation78">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <tableExists  tableName="MY_TABLE_NAME" />
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <comment>Creating table MY_TABLE_NAME</comment>
        <createTable tableName="MY_TABLE_NAME">
            <column name="M_ID" type="bigint">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_MY_TABLE_NAME_190" />
            </column>
            <column name="M_FORMAT" type="int" />
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    ...
    ...
    ...

    <changeSet author="me" id="indexCreation121">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <tableExists tableName="MY_TABLE_NAME"/>
            <not>
                <indexExists tableName="MY_TABLE_NAME" columnNames="M_FEEDER_ID"/>
            </not>
        </preConditions>
        <comment>Creating index for MY_TABLE_NAME</comment>
        <createIndex tableName="MY_TABLE_NAME" indexName="MY_INDEX_NAME">
            <column name="M_ID_INDEX"/>
        </createIndex>
    </changeSet>
    
    ...
    ...
    ...

</databaseChangeLog>
```

On the Liquibase **3.5.3**, creating the index used to be quick.
When I migrated to Liquibase **3.6.3**, I had a severe regression in performance.

What used to run in 1-2 minutes, now takes up to 20 minutes to complete.

The changelog does not define Unique Constraints.
While debugging, I noticed one of the many differences between the two versions. In the **3.5.3**, the `listConstraints` and `listColumns` methods from `UniqueConstraintSnapshotGenerator` are not called.
In the **3.6.3** version, these methods are called a lot, even though no unique constraints are defined in the changelog. I am guessing that they are here from the previously defined tables of the environment.

Some of these queries (see below) are called multiple times with the exact same parameters. I don't know if it's a maintenance step that was added in the **3.6.3**.

`2020-08-13 17:03:52,270 INFO [main] select ucc.owner as constraint_container, ucc.constraint_name as constraint_name, ucc.column_name, f.validated as constraint_validate from all_cons_columns ucc INNER JOIN all_constraints f ON ucc.owner = f.owner AND ucc.constraint_name = f.constraint_name where ucc.constraint_name='UC' and ucc.owner='DB' and ucc.table_name not like 'BIN$%' order by ucc.position`

I am not sure if this is the cause of the regression but honestly, I am out of ideas.
Does anybody know if this might be the cause of this regression?
Did they add new maintenance steps in Liquibase **3.6.3** that might be causing this big performance degradation?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to perform maintenance on your Oracle data dictionary. Databases that use Liquibase tend to drop and create more objects than the average Oracle database, which can cause performance problems with metadata queries.

First, gather optimizer statistics for fixed objects (V$ objects) and the data dictionary (ALL_ objects). This information helps Oracle build good execution plans for metadata queries. The below statement will take a few minutes but may only need to be run once a year:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_fixed_objects_stats;
    dbms_stats.gather_dictionary_stats;
end;
/
```

Another somewhat-common reason for data dictionary query problems is a large number of objects in the recycle bin. The recycle bin is great on production systems, where it lets you instantly recover from dropping the wrong table. But on a development environment, if thousands of objects are constantly dropped but not purged, those old objects can slow down some metadata queries.

```
--Count the number of objects in the recycle bin.
select count(*) from dba_recyclebin;
--Purge all of them if you don't need them. Must be run as SYS.
purge dba_recyclebin;
```

Those are two quick and painless solutions to some data dictionary problems. If that doesn't help, you may need to tune specific SQL statements, which may require a lot of information. For example - exactly how long does it take your system to run that query against ALL_CONS_COLUMNS? (On my database, it runs in much less than a second.)

Run Liquibase and then use a query like the one below to find the slowest metadata queries:

```
select elapsed_time/1000000 seconds, executions, sql_id, sql_fulltext, gv$sql.*
from gv$sql
order by elapsed_time desc;
```